# Docker registry in kubernetes with cert-manager

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ssl-certificate, docker-registry, cert-manager

I'm using [cert-manager](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager) for SSL management with configuration on ingress level. For example this config for `<myhost>.com` (skipping `metadata` and other not-related config parts):

```
kind: Certificate
spec:
  secretName: myhost-tls
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-dns
    kind: ClusterIssuer
---
kind: Ingress
...
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - myhost.com
    secretName: myhost-tls
...
```

Now I'm trying to move my docker registry into kubernetes cluster, but it requires certificate file to configure registry deployment.

Is it possible to use docker registry without SSL (because encryption can be done on ingress level) or use cert-manager to get certificate from docker registry?

Answer (score 0):

You can allow the insecure registry in the following way on each node in the cluster:

```
docker daemon --insecure-registry=255.255.255.255:5000
```

You can also edit /etc/default/docker and include the following line which will do the above for you:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry=5.179.232.65:5000"
```

The DOCKER_OPTS variable will automatically include that option for the Docker daemon.